# asp.net core: how to apply a ModelState error when a form is submitted via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, .net-5

I am trying to display the errors associated with a form.

The form has a validation performed on the client (works fine) and on the server (that's my issue). The actual submission code is done through an ajax call:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "text",
                data: fiscalYearData,
                success: function () {
                    showSuccess('Saved successfully');
                    closeForm();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                showError('An error occured');
                }
            });
```

Unfortunately, that is not satifying. In my controller, I'm returning a ModelSatte with all relevant errors provided:

```
                    if (ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);

                    // save the modified entity
                    await fiscalYearService.SaveFiscalYearAsync(fy, SecurityContext);
                    return Ok();
```

How can I modify the ajax error handling function to use the ModelState to display the error in the form itself?

**Edit** I apparently need to clarify what I would like to do:

I receive a ModelState containing errors error back from the ajax call. I would like to display these errors in the form in the same way they would have been displayed if I had submitted the form via a form submit button and page refresh: fields corresponding tot the error's keys should be marked in red with the corresponding error text displayed in the appropriate error labels.

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Comment: I'm afraid not (see my comment) but I'll upvote you for the effort. Thank you vers much for trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass ModelState error message to ajax,and put `error.responseText` into form.

Action:

```
if (ModelState.ErrorCount > 0) {
                //Customize your error message
                string messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                         .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                         .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) ? x.ErrorMessage : x.Exception.Message.ToString()));
                return BadRequest(messages);
            }
```

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "text",
                data: fiscalYearData,
                success: function () {
                    showSuccess('Saved successfully');
                    closeForm();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                showError(error.responseText);
                }
            });
```

**Update:**

If you want to validate like form post,I think you don't need to use ModelState,you can use `$("#xxform").valid()` in js.So that only when the model is valid,we will use ajax to post data to action.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
 public class TestModelState {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
       
    }
```

View:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MiddleName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"  value="submit" />
</form>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // check if the input is valid using a 'valid' property
            if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Test1/TestModelState",
                    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        //showSuccess('Saved successfully');
                        //closeForm();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        //console.log(error.responseText);
                    }
                });
            } 
               
            })

    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but that does not answer my question: I want the problematic fields in the form to be highlighted with the relevant error text as if I had submitted it as a form

Comment: Hello,I have updated my answer,you can try to use `$("#xxform").valid()`

Comment: Thanks again but that is still not what I ask. I think I might ot have been clear in my question: I do not want to validate the form again, I want to display the error contained in the ModelState received via ajax to the user in the same way as if I had user a form post instaed (i.e the fields linked by the ModelState errors keys in red with the corresponding error text in the appropriate labels)